# Notepad Regex, how to delete everything after x

Tags: regex, notepad++

So I got a list that is full with informations, and looks like:

```
'1','2','3','4','5','6',
```

and so on.

How can I delete everything after the 5th `'x'` part? Is there any way to count the `''` as groups or smh?

Comment: So it looks like you have a **comma-separated CSV file**, and you want to delete everything after the **5th column**. Right?

Comment: @Tobias if my answer was helpful, please accept it :)

Answer (score 0):

It's a little cheesy but sure:

```
^(([^,\r\n]+,){4}[^,]+).*
```

replace with

```
\1
```

That will capture the first 5 groups of a line and replace the entire line with those first 5 groups.  Groups being 1 or more non comma characters (and not end of line) separated by commas.

Thanks to Sebastian Proske for pointing out the wrap problem :)

Comment: If there can be lines with less than 5 groups this won't work properly.

Comment: Hm, why wouldn't it work with less than 5 groups? It just won't match so then it won't change the line in Notepad++.  I don't think he's looking to capture data, just strip past a point.

Comment: Have you tested? It will overlap over lines with less than 5 groups, e.g. `short,row,here` newline `now,this,contains,5,elements,start,deleting,here`

Comment: ah crud!  You are right.  I'll update it.  Thank you!